# JQuery Datepicker date format issues

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have looked everywhere for a answer and cant find the thing that happens to me.

i am trying to use a range datepicker and it works fine until i set the format after i select a start date it removes the datepicker and i cant fill the end date. it is more then likely a problem with the if statement but i dont really know much about jquery.

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
       dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("[id$=from]").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("[id$=to]").val());
            return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("[id$=from]").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("[id$=to]").val());
            if (!date1 || date2) {
                $("[id$=from]").val(dateText);
                $("[id$=to]").val("");
                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
            } else {
                $("[id$=to]").val(dateText);
                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a little confusing, you  have an element with an ID `datepicker`, but what are these elements with ID's ending in `...from` and `...to` ?

Comment: are you talking about [id$=from]? i copied that strate from stack overflow and its the only way the calendar binds to the textbox the only issue comes in when i put in dateFormat:yy-mm-dd.

Comment: But... you have to have an element with an ID ending with `...from`, otherwise what's the point?

Comment: should i post the html aswell? i really suck with jquery i have no idea whats going on there.

Comment: i have a html input called from and one called to

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle of your code